# Highcharts Spiderweb after Gauge causes strange behavior

Tags: highcharts

It seems like if you put a spiderweb after a gauge, the spiderweb suddenly has a background.  Check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hoqk6u4h/

If you swap the order of the JS around, namely that the spiderweb gets spawned before the gauge, the strange background will be gone.  However in the current order, the spiderweb gets an odd background, and I'm not really sure what is causing this.

The html structure is pretty basic,

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.src.js"></script>

<div id="selected-streamer-weekly-uptime" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left;"></div>
<div id="container" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

JS is a bit longer but is just spawning the gauge and the spiderweb with some options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a quark of how gauge charts are created.  In `highcharts-more.js` (line 65) to create the gauge chart, a pane object is extended and global settings for background are re-defined.

To correct this, just add:

```
    pane: {
        background: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        }
    },
```

Into you second `Highcharts.Chart` call.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hoqk6u4h/1/).